# How to create a response format on ASP.net webapi as in the picture?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How to create a response format on ASP.net webapi as in the picture ?

error response:

[image: error response]

success response:

[image: success response]

Comment: Do you mean, that your controller methods should return some DTO, which should be serialized as a picture with formatted JSON?

Answer (score 1):

First of create your DTOs

```
public class SuccessDTO
{
    public int success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<RoleDTO> data{ get; set; }
}
public class RoleDTO
{
   public string roles_name{ get; set; }
   public string description { get; set; }       
}
public class ErrorDTO
{
    public int success { get; set; }
    public ErrorCodeDTO error { get; set; }
}
public class ErrorCodeDTO
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Then return the objects from the web api

```
public IHttpActionResult GetSuccess()
{
    var success = new SuccessDTO 
    { 
        success = 1, 
        message = "Ok", 
        data = new List<RoleDTO>()
        { 
            new RoleDTO 
            { 
                roles_name = "Admin", 
                description = "admin" 
            }, 
            new RoleDTO 
            { 
                roles_name = "Administrator", 
                description = "Administrator" 
            } 
        } 
    };
    return Ok(success);
}

public IHttpActionResult GetError()
{
    var error = new ErrorDTO 
    { 
        success = 0, 
        error = new ErrorCodeDTO 
                {
                    code = 0,
                    message = "invalid username and password"
                }
    };
    return BadRequest(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the data in defined format.

//Return Object

```
   public class ReturnThisOBJ
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string success { get; set; }
        public List<yourClass> data{ get; set; }
    }
    public class yourClass
    {
       public string roles_name{ get; set; }
       public string description { get; set; }       
    }
```

[JSON Serialization And Deserialization](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/json-serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just followed how it is done in PageResult in System.Web.OData in order to return any result they want.

So here you go. you need to write these classes to return from any method.

```
    public class error
    {
        public int code { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public abstract class MyResult
    {
        private string _message;
        private bool _success;
        private error _error;

        protected MyResult(bool success, string message)
        {
            this.success = success;
            if (this.success == true)
            {
                message = "OK";
            }
            this.message = message;
            if (this.success == false)
            {
                this.error = new error
                {
                    code = 0,
                    message = this.message
                };
            }

        }

        protected MyResult(bool success, error error)
        {
            this.success = success;
            if (this.success == true)
            {
                error = null;
                this.message = "OK";
            }
            this.error = error;
            if (this.success == false)
            {
                this.message = this.error.message;
            }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public bool success
        {
            get
            {
                return _success;
            }
            private set
            {
                _success = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string message
        {
            get
            {
                return _message;
            }
            set
            {
                _message = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public error error
        {
            get
            {
                return _error;
            }
            set
            {
                _error = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    [JsonObject]
    public class MyResult<T> : MyResult, IEnumerable<T>
    {
        public MyResult(IEnumerable<T> data, bool success = true, string message = "OK") : base(success, message)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public MyResult(string errorMessage) : base(false, errorMessage) { }
        public MyResult(error error) : base(false, error) { }

        [DataMember]
        public IEnumerable<T> data { get; private set; }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return data.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return data.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

MyResult is the class we'll be returning from our controllers.
And now Data class, which you can use any class with any name you want.

```
    public class Data
    {
        public string role { get; set; }
        public int? id { get; set; }
    }
```

And now here how I'm calling it from my controllers

```
    public class MyDataFormatController : ApiController
    {
        List<Data> data = new List<Data>();

        public MyResult<Data> Get()
        {
            data.Add(new Data { id = 1, role = "admin" });
            data.Add(new Data { id = 2, role = "manager" });
            data.Add(new Data { id = 3, role = "employee" });

            return new MyResult<Data>(data);
        }

        [Route("api/mydataformat/errormessage")]
        public MyResult<Data> GetError()
        {
            return new MyResult<Data>("No Data");
        }

        [Route("api/mydataformat/errorwithcode")]
        public MyResult<Data> GetErrorWithCode()
        {
            return new MyResult<Data>(new error { code = 101, message = "Invalid Data" });
        }
    }
```